# Creating a new variable by detecting max value for each id

Tags: r

My data set contains three variables:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,5,5)
ind <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
price <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6)
mdata <- data.frame(id,ind,price)
```

I need to create a new variable (ind2) that is if ind=0, then ind2=0. 
also, if ind=1, then ind2=0, unless the price value is max, then ind2=1.

The new data looks like:

```
id  ind ind2    price

1   0   0   1
1   0   0   2
1   0   0   3
1   0   0   4
1   0   0   5
1   0   0   6
2   1   0   1
2   1   0   2
2   1   0   3
2   1   1   4
5   1   0   1
5   1   0   2
5   1   0   3
5   1   0   4
5   1   0   5
5   1   1   6
```

Comment: @nongkrong. Yes, what's the problem?

Comment: I need to do this for each id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
mdata %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(ind2 = +(ind == 1L & price == max(price)))

#    id ind price ind2
# 1   1   0     1    0
# 2   1   0     2    0
# 3   1   0     3    0
# 4   1   0     4    0
# 5   1   0     5    0
# 6   1   0     6    0
# 7   2   1     1    0
# 8   2   1     2    0
# 9   2   1     3    0
# 10  2   1     4    1
# 11  5   1     1    0
# 12  5   1     2    0
# 13  5   1     3    0
# 14  5   1     4    0
# 15  5   1     5    0
# 16  5   1     6    1
```

Or if you prefer `data.table`

```
setDT(mdata)[, ind2 := +(ind == 1L & price == max(price)), by = id]
```

Or with base R

```
mdata$ind2 <- unlist(lapply(split(mdata,mdata$id), 
                            function(x) +(x$ind == 1L & x$price == max(x$price))))
```

Comment: Thank you @Pierre Lafortune... what does '1L' stand for?

Comment: the "L" is to tell R that you want integers. A little more efficiency.

Comment: @RichardScriven.. what's backticks?

Comment: Forget everything I said :)